# Sort a list of object w.r.t to a particular member/state

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have a list of java object that have 4 members.

```
int id;
String name;
String age;
int order;
```

I want to sort the list of this object w.r.t `order`.

Comment: Take a look at Comparable and/or Comparator interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private int order;
    //accessors
}
```

Use Custom [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
    List<Foo> list = null;
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Foo>() {

          public int compare(Foo o1, Foo o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1.getOrder()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf( o2.getOrder()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I was used to doing this for sorting on integers, but it doesn't work on very large values, because of potential overflow. It's better to use Integer.valueOf(o1.getOrder()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.getOrder()), or compare them with > or <, or, in Java 7, Integer.compare(o1.getOrder(), o2.getOrder())

Comment: Thanks, Can you give me an example

Comment: Yes: try comparing -2 and Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can Implement java.lang.Comparable interface and put the sorting logic in compareTo(T o) or else
2. you can have custom java.lang.Comparator and  have the logic in compare() method.

I would suggest to implement custom Comparator, as later if you try to modify your sorting criteria, ll be easily done.

Answer (score 1):

Make the object implement `Comparable`.

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int order;

    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return p.order - this.order;
    }
}
```

You can then use objects of this class `Person` in any sorted list such as `PriorityQueue` or you could simply use `Collections.sort(personList)` for that.

Comment: using a custom comparator is more streight forward since there is no natural way of ordering Persons - for numbers there is a natural definition of their ordering behavior

Answer (score 0):

Use a **PriorityQueue** and let your objects extend **Comparable**.

You also have to implement the **compareTo(object o)** method.