# Sorting an arraylist of my own type in Java

Tags: java, collections

I have a type in Java called Item which is defined as follows:

```
private Integer itemNo;
private String itemName;
private String itemDescription;
...
```

And I would like to be able to sort an arraylist of this type in descending order according to itemName.

From what I read, this can be done via:

```
Collections.sort(items, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Where items is:

```
ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

But I find that the call to Collections.sort gives me a:

```
Item cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

Run time exception.

Can anyone advise on what I need to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare Item to be [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), and implement the [comapreTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method to compare `itemName` in *reverse* order (ie compare "*that* to *this*", rather than the normal "*this* to *that*").

Like this:

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    private Integer itemNo;
    private String itemName;
    private String itemDescription;

    public int compareTo(Item o) {
        return o.itemName.compareTo(itemName); // Note reverse of normal order
    }

    // rest of class
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need your custom `Item` to implement `Comparable` , or otherwise you can do it [using Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076427/sort-a-list-of-object-w-r-t-to-a-particular-member-state)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably make Item implement [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), **or** create a [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to your Item, and use [Collections.sort(List,Comparator)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

**code snap:**

Comparator:

```
public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        //reverse order: o2 is compared to o1, instead of o1 to o2.
        return o2.getItemName().compareTo(o1.getItemName()); 
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    Collections.sort(list,new MyComparator());
```

(*)note that the `static` keyword in `MyComparator`'s declaration is because I implemented it as an inner class, if you implement this class as an outer class, you should remove this keyword

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and define the [`compareTo(T o)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method.

See also:

- [How to use Comparable Interface](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-use-comparable-interface.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your Item class implement the java.lang.Comparable interface.

```
public class Item implements Comparable<Item> {

   // your code here, including an implementation of the compare method
}
```