# ArrayList sorting issue in Android

Tags: android, sorting, arraylist

I've an ArrayList of objects.

```
ArrayList<Item> blog_titles = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

I want to sort the ArrayList in the descending order of one of the datamembers which is a DateTime value stored as String (**timestamp** in the code below).

```
public class BlogItem implements Item, Comparable<BlogItem> {

    public final String id;
    public final String heading;
    public final String summary;
    public final String description;
    public final String thumbnail;
    public final String timestamp;  // format:- 2013-02-05T13:18:56-06:00
    public final String blog_link;

    public BlogItem(String id, String heading, String summary, String description, String thumbnail, String timestamp, String blog_link) {      
        this.id = id;
        this.heading = heading;
        this.summary = summary;
        this.description = description;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;   // format:- 2013-02-05T13:18:56-06:00
        this.blog_link = blog_link;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(BlogItem o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.timestamp.compareTo(o.timestamp);
    }

}
```

Item is a generic interface:

```
public interface Item { 
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```

Now when i'm trying to sort the ArrayList like:

```
Collections.sort(blog_titles);
```

I get the following error message:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Item>). The inferred type Item is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

How do i fix the above error & is this the correct approach to sort the ArrayList in this case ?

Comment: Refer this link <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514451/sorting-an-arraylist-of-my-own-type-in-java">this</a> It will help you to sort out type data.

Comment: I've implemented the same concept which is mentioned in the solution...however i'm getting a different error msg here

Comment: what type error you getting?

Comment: Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>)... basically that's the issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `blog_titles` list is a list of `Item`.

`Item` itself is not `Comparable`, while `BlogItem` is.

Either declare `blog_titles` as a `ArrayList<BlogItem>`, or make `Item` extend `Comparable`

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this..

Collections.sort(blog_titles, new Comparator<BlogItem>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(BlogItem lhs, BlogItem rhs) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (int)(rhs.timestamp - lhs.timestamp);
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Sourav here in my answer timestamp's datatype is long.